# UIBarButtonItem does not show on UIToolbar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

In iOS 7 the UIBarButtonItem does not show on my UIToolbar that pops up at the bottom of a tableview.

```
UIToolbar *actionToolbar;
UIBarButtonItem *actionButton;
```

I am adding it like this:

```
actionToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 524, 320, 44)];

actionButton =
                 [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                 initWithTitle:@"Delete"
                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                 target:self
                 action:@selector(noAction:)]
                 autorelease];

[actionToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:actionButton]];
```

And here is the code for displaying the UIToolbar:

```
- (void)showActionToolbar:(BOOL)show
{
    CGRect toolbarFrame = actionToolbar.frame;
    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    if (show)
    {
        TOOLBAR_DISPLAYED = TRUE;
        toolbarFrame.origin.y = actionToolbar.superview.frame.size.height - toolbarFrame.size.height;
        tableViewFrame.size.height -= toolbarFrame.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        TOOLBAR_DISPLAYED = FALSE;
        toolbarFrame.origin.y = actionToolbar.superview.frame.size.height;
        tableViewFrame.size.height += toolbarFrame.size.height;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    actionToolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;

    //I use this now in iOS7 to show the toolbar as purple otherwise it shows white
    actionToolbar.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.10 green:0.10 blue:0.43 alpha:0.5];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This works fine on previous versions and I am lost as to what the issue might be now.

Comment: In iOS 7 the button will not be bordered. It will appear just as text. Make sure your tint color is set. Perhaps the text of the button and the toolbar are the same color.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I tried changing the tint and background colors on all these widgets but still couldn't get it displayed on the toolbar. In the end switched to using a UIView with a UIButton instead where it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

set  the tint color. In my case toolbar was black. So I set tint color to white and it worked.